# How to tidy up urls

Tags: url, structure, permalinks

Do anyone have tips on how to create more readable links to pages?

I do not know what the correct term is, but wordpress have a feature called permalink, which tidy up the url so that is more readable (eg. http://example.com/2012/post-name/).

What I am looking for does not necessarily have to be the same technique as the one wordpress use.

Or is the only simple solution good old directory structure?

Thank you!

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: You are talking about URL re-writing if I'm not mistaken. URL rewriting depends on which programming language and which server (IIS/Apache etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to use `mod_rewrite`. If you are using a paid hosting service, chances are you already have this enabled in Apache. If not, there are lots of tutorials on building it.

Now plan how you want your URLs to look like. For example, you want to turn *http://yoursite.com/tutorials.php?req=tutorial&id=3&page=0* into *http://yoursite.com/tutorials/3/0.php*

Open or create your `.htaccess` file and add something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tutorials/(.*)/(.*).php /tutorials.php?req=tutorial&tut_id=$1&page=$2
```

Note the pattern: `(.*)` are where variables, such as `$1` are placed, in order.

Source and more information: [http://www.devshed.com](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Apache/Search-Engine-Friendly-URLs-with-mod-rewrite/)

Comment: What language is `mod_rewrite`?

Comment: It's not a language, it's a module of Apache, your web server. Again, if you are using some commercial webhosting, you can most likely forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

There's always http://tinyurl.com, which allows you to create short links from any given long urls. If you are trying to do this from a program, there's even an API: http://tinyurl.com/779a2g9.

However, this assumes that I am understanding your question correctly.

Comment: Nope, you have miss understood me. I was rather looking for a way to make a url more readable/easy to memorize etc, not only shorter.

Máté Galei however seems to have gotten me right.